# How do I play .rm files in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, realmedia

I tried downloading VLC player with these instructions to play a .rm file.

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

VLC downloaded just fine, but it is unable to play my .rm file. Is there a codec I need to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need `ubuntu-restricted-extras` to get the right codec, which is a Real Player one.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

VLC cannot play `.rm` apparently, but mplayer will.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-mplayer
```